# When returning the view through the controller, the view to be returned cannot be located

Tags: spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf

I made sure the annotation in my controller class is '@Controller'
Then when I hold down Ctrl + click the left mouse button, the idea prompts 'annot find declaration to go to', but when I start the service, the view page can be correctly redirected and can also be accessed The data passed, what is the reason for this, and how to solve it?
At the same time, the template engine I use is thymeleaf, and when I use thymeleaf expressions in the html page, idea cannot correctly prompt me for the data passed from the controller, that is, there is no prompt in '${}', and I can get the passed data correctly even if I write it without a prompt, how can I make the idea have the correct prompt
[An example of an html page that cannot be located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfaT2.png)

The following is a picture without a correct prompt when using the thymeleaf expression to get the passed data
[Example without completion prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU4Fz.png)

This is manually written when there is no completion prompt, but it can be correctly obtained at runtime
[Example without completion prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUPHe.png)

I have tried adding the following configuration in the config file but it has no effect

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZZFE.png)

And tried to re-enable the plugin in the idea settings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCtso.png)